# Using renderer2 to access native element

Tags: angular, angular-renderer2

Is there any difference in these two methods of accessing native element from security perspective?

```
SomeDirective implements OnInit{
  constructor(
    elementRef : ElementRef,
    renderer : Renderer2){}

 ngOnInit(){
  //method 1
  const el1 = this.elementRef.nativeElement;
  //method 2
  const el2 = this.renderer.GetRootElement(this.elementRef.nativeElement , true);
  //then use some method like this
  (el1 || el2).ScrollIntoView()
```

Comment: Dont think so, but would strongly recommend you to just use the Renderer2 to make changes to your domElement.  IMO the security aspect comes in when you are modifying the DOM directly from elementRef.nativeElement

Comment: @wscttc but i have to use nativeElement in order to scroll into view, so you're saying i'd be better off with method2?

Comment: If you are just using it to scrollIntoView, i believe its fine. 

The security issue comes when people try to edit innerHTML or innerText of the element without sanitizing the values appended